# Registering Api controller routes with MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I added one Api controller to my MVC project. And made following changes:

My WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetFirms",
                routeTemplate: "api/B2bApi/GetFirms",
                defaults: new { controller =  "B2bApiController", action= "GetFirms" });
        }
    }
```

I register this route in Global.asax (Last line)

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

I checked in debugged and saw that my routes are registered. So here is my controller:

```
public class B2bApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetFirms()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
```

When i navigate to

> /api/B2bApi/GetFirms

i'm getting

> 404 error

.

What is the correct way to register api routes?

Answer (score 3):

If **asp.net-mvc-4**

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

if **asp.net-mvc-5 and asp.net-web-api-2**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

must be placed above

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

     //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // use if mvc5       
     WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); // use if mvc4
     FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are creating a separate project for WebApi.

If I am not wrong, you've not registered `WebApiConfig` in `Global.asax`.

**Remove this**

```
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

and add

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

It looks like -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a controller for the defaults remove the keyword "controller" in your controllers name.

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetFirms",
        routeTemplate: "api/B2bApi/GetFirms",
        defaults: new { controller = "B2bApi", action = "GetFirms" });
```

Also as others have said move your register to the top.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```